# How fetch "Date" field from HTML form and convert it into MySQL Date

Tags: java, date, jsp, servlets

as a title I need to fetch Date input the is sent from HTML page to Servlet. In this servlet I need to convert this data format to the MySQL format.
in fact, I thought I had already done everything correctly but, if I introduce a date before January 1, 1970 I have problems.

This is my code when I parse the date from HTML page:

```
 Date authorDateOfBirth1= null;
 try {
     authorDateOfBirth1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(request.getParameter("authorDateOfBirth1"));
 }
 catch (ParseException exceptionInParsingDate) {
        out.print("Error in parsing date author1 " + exceptionInParsingDate.getMessage());
 }
```

Then, each time I need an object Mysql Date I use:

```
statementAuthor.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(authorDateOfBirth.getTime()));
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are your “problems” you speak of?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column in the database should be of type [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

Be careful of your `import` statements. You may be mixing up the Java types, `java.sql.Date` and `java.util.Date`. One represents a moment, while the other represents a date-only but actually is a moment underneath. **Use neither** class.

You are using terrible date-time classes in Java that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

The birth date member field of your `Author` class should be of type `LocalDate`.

For a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "1960-01-23" ) ;
```

Exchange *java.time* objects with the database using JDBC 4.2 and later.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieve from database.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

To generate text in other formats, see the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

Comment: OK, if I understand correctly, if I simply want to take the "<input type = date> </input>" format from my HTML page, in the servlet I simply need to create a localTime object and when I have to insert it into the database I no longer need to create a "MySQL Date" object but simply pass the LocalDate object. it's correct?

Comment: @DavideNetti I do not know what you mean by "a "MySQL Date" object". But the earlier part of your comment sounds correct. You have text coming in from a web page. You need to parse that text into a meaningful date-time object. For a date-only value, that would be the `LocalDate` value. To store that value in a database, you need a column defined with a date-only data type to hold the value of your date-only Java object (a `LocalDate`). JDBC 4.2 and later communicates your `LocalDate` object to the database.